# Class object creation in C++

Tags: c++, class, object

I have a basic C++ question which I really should know the answer to.

Say we have some class `A` with constructor `A(int a)`. What is the difference between:

```
A test_obj(4);
```

and

```
A test_obj = A(4);
```

?

I generally use the latter syntax, but after looking up something unrelated in my trusty C++ primer I realized that they generally use the former. The difference between these two is often discussed in the context of built-in types (e.g. `int a(6)` vs `int a = 6`), and my understanding is that in this case they are equivalent.

However, in the case of user-defined classes, are the two approaches to defining an object equivalent? Or is the latter option first default constructing `test_obj`, and then using the copy constructor of `A` to assign the return value of `A(4)` to `test_obj`? If it's this second possibility, I imagine there could be some performance differences between the two approaches for large classes.

I'm sure this question is answered somewhere on the internet, even here, but I couldn't search for it effectively without finding questions asking the difference between the first option and using `new`, which is unrelated.

Comment: *I generally use the latter syntax* --  Why?  You'll be hard-pressed to find an experienced C++ programmer use that syntax on purpose.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie No particularly good reason, I just do. I'm open to changing. I never really thought about it before.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie back to the original question, what is the difference?

Comment: *I imagine there could be some performance differences between the two approaches for large classes* -- [Not necessarily](https://godbolt.org/g/LhBtJe).  Look at `main` in the assembly listing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A test_obj = A(4);` conceptually does indeed construct a temporary `A` object, then copy/move-construct `test_obj` from the temporary, and then destruct the temporary.

However this process is a candidate for [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) which means the compiler is allowed to treat it as `A test_obj(4);` after verifying that the copy/move-constructor exists and is accessible.

From C++17 it will be mandatory for compilers to do this; prior to that it was optional but typically compilers did do it.

Comment: If `A test_obj = A(4);` is the same as `A test_obj = 4;` does that mean that using the [`explicit` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) will cause it to throw compile time errors?

Comment: @UnholySheep good point. Removed that bit from my answer as it's not really related to OP's question

Comment: Explicit copy constructor indeed breaks this for me.

Comment: @UnholySheep: they are not the same. if the constructor is explicit then the code won't compile. in the version: `A test_obj = 4;` while it is ok in `A test_obj = A(4);`

Answer (score 3):

Performance-wise these are equivalent, even if you have a non-standard copy constructor, as mandated by [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision). This is guaranteed since C++17 but permitted and widely present even in compilers conforming to earlier standards.

Try for yourself, with all optimizations turned off and the standard forced into C++11 (or C++03, change the command line in the top right):
https://godbolt.org/g/GAq7fi